# The usage of "whatever" in a sentence

Tags: comparison

Is it correct to say that "whatever" here suggests a conditional?

"The meaning of a poem is whatever meaning a reader assigns to it."

I am not sure whether the sentence can be reworded as

either
"If a reader assigns a certain meaning to a poem, then the poem has it."

or
"If a poem has a certain meaning, then the meaning is assigned by its readers."

Could someone help explain the difference?

Thank you very much,
Leon

Comment: _Whatever_ is not a conditional.  For each person who reads a poem, the meaning is what the poem means _to them_.

Comment: Thank you @Kate. So can I say that "whatever" here serves to define what the meaning of a poem is?

Comment: _Whatever_ doesn't define anything; it just indicates that every reader attributes their own meaning to the poem, no matter _what_ it may be.